# UIWebView document with custom margins (was:not scrolling as expected)

Tags: ios, xcode, uiwebview, scroll, margins

-EDIT-
I just created a test document in Landscape mode and it displayed fine. 
It appears that the documents I'm working with have custom margins, smaller than normal.
Is there a way to adjust the way such documents are displayed so that all the text can be viewed on screen?
/-EDIT-

I have a piece of code to display a .doc document, which is in landscape mode:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];   
   _myWebView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 760)];   
   NSURL *myUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://pathToDoc/myDoc.doc"];  
   NSURLRequest *myRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:myUrl];
   [_myWebView loadRequest:myRequest];    
   [self.view addSubview:_myWebView];
}
```

This displays the document in a scrollable view, however; scrolling completely to the right, a chunk of the document is truncated, meaning not all of the text can be read.

Can anyone shed any light on why this would be?

Comment: did you try to adding the uiwebview as subview to the view before loading the request? Does this happen with other documents?

Comment: Adding subview before loading request produces the same result.
It seems to be happening with all documents I'm working with that have been saved in landscape mode. Portrait documents work as expected.

Comment: try this: _myWebView.scalesPageToFit = YES;

Comment: Thanks, that shrinks the page down, so no scrolling, but there's still a bit trimmed off the right hand edge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only took a few months but I got there eventually. This one line is all that's missing:

```
_myWebView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
```